# My Own Crawler Does Not Work If I Change The Attribute

Tags: python, oop, loops, recursion, foreach

[Check The Gist](https://gist.github.com/erayerdin/ad319994326a8a236bdb)

Whenever I change `limit` attribute of the object and call `crawl` function, code terminates.

However, code works if I don't change the limit attribute:

```
from api import Crawler

if __name__ == "__main__":
    mycrawler = Crawler("http://metasozluk.com/")
    mycrawler.crawl()
```

Let me explain a bit more about code. This is -so called- a simple crawler I tried to code. `limit[0]` attribute is the limit of crawling a page. `limit[1]` is added by 1 whenever the crawl function finishes [as you can see at the line 54 of api.py](https://gist.github.com/erayerdin/ad319994326a8a236bdb#file-api-py-L54).

[From 26th to 31st lines of api.py](https://gist.github.com/erayerdin/ad319994326a8a236bdb#file-api-py-L26-L31), I check if there's a limit and if there is, make sure if `limit[0]` and `limit[1]` are equal (and if equal, function returns).

However, if I determine a limit as in [app.py](https://gist.github.com/erayerdin/ad319994326a8a236bdb#file-app-py), the code does not run `mycrawler.crawl()` function and terminates, while it works if I do like above. I don't know what is the problem here.

#### Basic Explanation

What I want to do is:

- Check if there is a limit.

  - If there is, look how many times did crawling run?

    - If limit and runtimes equal, return.
  - If there is not, check crawling queue.

    - If there is no URL to crawl, return.

Comment: Does it show any error?

Comment: On second look your asking if self.limit[0] != 0 but never counting down self.limit[0], so your code stays in a loop calling it self over and over again. I think its caused by the elif len(self.urls) == 0 statement. Maybe you should try if self.limit[0] != 0 or len(self.urls) == 0: and then ask if len(self.urls) == 0 in the first If statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Sorry, i (think) have to do some editing to the code. :/

<s>Does this works for you?</s>

```
import re, requests, logging, os, time, json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

class Crawler(object):
    logger = logging.getLogger("crawler_logger")
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    file_handler = logging.FileHandler(os.getcwd()+"/logs/{}.log".format( str(int(round(time.time()*1000))) ))
    file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    terminal_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    terminal_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    log_format = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s")
    file_handler.setFormatter(log_format)
    terminal_handler.setFormatter(log_format)
    logger.addHandler(terminal_handler)
    logger.addHandler(file_handler)

    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.logger.info("Initializing Crawler object on '{}' domain with {} urls.".format(args[0], str(args)))
        self.domain = args[0]
        self.urls = list(args)
        self.crawled = []
        self.limit = [0, 0]
        self.dump_file = "urls.json"

    def crawl(self):
        # while urls in self.urls
        while self.urls:
            if self.limit[0] != 0:
                if self.limit[0] == self.limit[1]:
                    self.logger.info("Limit reached, writing to file and returns.")
                    with open(self.dump_file, "w") as dump_file:
                        dump_file.write(json.dumps(self.urls))
                    return

            try:
                self.logger.info("Connecting to {}...".format(self.urls[0]))
                response = requests.get(self.urls[0])
                response.encoding = "utf-8"
                self.logger.info("Analyzing to structures...")
                soup = bs(response.text, "html.parser")
                links = soup.find_all("a", {"href" : re.compile("^/")})
                hrefs = [x.attrs["href"] for x in links]
                self.logger.info("Links are checked if they are crawled...")
                for href in hrefs:
                    if self.domain[0:-1]+href in self.crawled:
                        self.logger.warn("{} already crawled.".format(str(href)))
                        pass
                    else: self.urls.append(self.domain[0:-1]+href)
                self.crawled.append(self.urls[0])
                # Remove first url from reversed self.urls list
                self.urls[::-1].pop()
                self.limit[1]+=1
                self.logger.info("Reached count {}/{}".format(str(self.limit[1]), str(self.limit[0])))
            except Exception as e:
                self.logger.error("Crawling function raised an error, passing: {}".format(str(e)))

        if len(self.urls) == 0:
            self.logger.info("No url left to crawl, returns.")
            with open(self.dump_file, "w+") as dump_file:
                dump_file.write(json.dumps(self.urls))
            return


if __name__ == "__main__":
    mycrawler = Crawler("http://metasozluk.com/")
    mycrawler.limit[0] = 5
    mycrawler.crawl()
```

Comment: This worked for me, thanks. ^^ [Here's a cute potato for you.](https://inallseriousnessblog.files.wordpress.com/2015/03/kawai-potato.png)

Comment: There's a little problem, I also want it to crawl forever and dump to json file if limit is zero. However, I think I can handle this by myself. :)

Comment: Yay! Glad i could help. I'm courios about logging without setting a limit if it does logg the same but i always mess up which log is which when testing the code :/